# C++, SDL, function doesnt seem to change main surface after first launch

Tags: c++, sdl

Here is the code of draw()
My problem is that it draws things only once, then it draws the same.
I am using SLD_Flip(surface) after it.
sqrbmp, applebmp, blank are surfaces with BMP loaded
des is a rectangle
screen is main surface
It is supposed to draw a game map.
Where is my bad?

```
// includes, defines etc.

const int mapx = 32; // 640 / 20(bmp size)
const int mapy = 24; // 480 / 20

//nothing important

SDL_Event keys;

SDL_Surface * screen = NULL;
SDL_Surface * blank = NULL;
SDL_Surface * sqrbmp = NULL;
SDL_Surface * applebmp = NULL;

SDL_Rect des;

int map[mapy][mapx];

// nothing important

// nothing important

struct square
{
    square(int xt, int yt, int dirt);
    int x;
    int y;
    int dir;
};

std::vector <square> snake;

square::square(int xt, int yt, int dirt)
{
    x = xt;
    y = yt;
    dir = dirt;
    snake.push_back(*this);
}

bool squareontile(int x, int y)
{
    // returns true if there is square on that tile
}

void draw()
{
    for(int yt = 0 ; yt < mapy; yt++)
    {
        for(int xt = 0 ; xt < mapx; xt++)
        {
            des.y = yt * 20;
            des.x = xt * 20;
            if(squareontile(xt,yt) == 1)
            {
                SDL_BlitSurface(sqrbmp, NULL, screen, &des);
            }
            else
            {
                switch(map[yt][xt])
                {
                    case 5:
                        SDL_BlitSurface(applebmp, NULL, screen, &des);
                    break;

                    default:
                        SDL_BlitSurface(blank, NULL, screen, &des);
                    break;
                }
           }
        }
    }
}

// nothing important

void checkmap()
{
    for(int yt = 0 ; yt < mapy; yt++)
    {
        for(int xt = 0 ; xt < mapx; xt++)
        {
            if(squareontile(xt,yt) == 0 && map[yt][xt] != 5)
            {
                map[yt][xt] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

bool checksnake()
{
    for(int a = 0; a < snake.size() ; a++)
    {
        for(int b = 0; b < snake.size() ; b++)
        {
            if(snake[a].y == snake[b].y && snake[a].x == snake[b].x && a != b)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

// nothing important

void apple()
{
    if(!appleisonmap())
    {
        int y;
        int x;
        do
        {
            y = rand() % mapy;
            x = rand() % mapx;
        } while(squareontile(x,y));
        map[y][x] = 5;
    }
}

// nothing important


int main( int argc, char * args[] )
{
    // nothing important
    SDL_Init( SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING );
    screen = SDL_SetVideoMode( 640, 480, 24, SDL_SWSURFACE );
    applebmp = SDL_LoadBMP("apple.bmp"); // 20x20
    blank = SDL_LoadBMP("blank.bmp"); // 20x20
    sqrbmp = SDL_LoadBMP( "sqr.bmp" ); // 20x20
    for(int b = 7 ; b > 0 ; b--)
    {
        square(5,b,1);
    }
    while(!exitv && !game_over)
    {
        draw();
        game_over = checksnake();
        SDL_Flip( screen );
        SDL_Delay(100);
        while( SDL_PollEvent( & keys ) )
        {
            if( keys.type == SDL_QUIT )
            {
                exitv = true;
            }

            // detecting other keys, input for moving, ya know

        }
        checkmap();
        apple();
        checksquare();
    }
    SDL_FreeSurface( sqrbmp );
    SDL_FreeSurface( applebmp );
    SDL_FreeSurface( blank );
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The `default:` should be under the `case`

Comment: The default has nothing to do with it. We need more data, a full but simplified program would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Ahh found the error. I just forgot 1 function and the snake wasnt moving.

Comment: What function? Stack Overflow is a repository of knowledge, not your personal helpdesk, so Q&A are expected to help other people as well as you. Therefore, please provide the _full_ solution.